# Vibration on Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, vibration

Im currently working on an application using `Xamarin` android. I cannot get the device to `vibrate` though.

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)Activity.GetSystemService(Context.VibratorService);
vibrator.Vibrate(100);
```

It builds but crashes when I press the button that is linked to the code.

Comment: Have you checked your Android permissions? And you should also do a check for the presence of vibrate on the device before calling the vibrate function

Comment: I didnt think that was necessary when developing on Xamarin in Visual Studio. Where do I put the permissions?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it and added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> to AndroidManifest.XML and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This solves the problem 
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Vibrate permission is required and must be configured in the Android project. This can be added in the following ways:

Open the AssemblyInfo.cs file under the Properties folder and add:

**C#**

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Vibrate)]
```

OR

**Update Android Manifest**:

Open the AndroidManifest.xml file under the Properties folder and add the following inside of the manifest node.

**XML**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Or right click on the Android project and open the project's properties. Under Android Manifest find the Required permissions: area and check the VIBRATE permission. This will automatically update the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Add a reference to Xamarin.Essentials in your class:

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;
```

The Vibration functionality can be requested for a set amount of time or the default of 500 milliseconds.

```
try
{
    // Use default vibration length
    Vibration.Vibrate();

    // Or use specified time
    var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    Vibration.Vibrate(duration);
}
catch (FeatureNotSupportedException ex)
{
    // Feature not supported on device
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Other error has occurred.
}
```

Cancellation of device vibration can be requested with the Cancel method:

```
try
{
    Vibration.Cancel();
}
catch (FeatureNotSupportedException ex)
{
    // Feature not supported on device
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Other error has occurred.
}
```

ref - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/vibrate?tabs=android